# Remove rows contains certain value from spatial dataframe - solved

Tags: r, data-manipulation, spatial-data-frame

I want to remove the rows that have certain values from the spatial `data.frame` since the standard R `grep()` seems not propagate through all slots of an `sp` class object.

`bd@data[- grep("xcluded", bd@data$Notes),]`

It gives me an error:

> Error: trying to get slot "data" from an object (class "data.frame") that is not an S4 object

I read that `sp.na.omit` can remove `NA` but don't know how to remove the rows have a certain value(eg. remove rows that have "exclude" in bd@data$Notes). Any suggestions?

Sorry I'm not able to create a shapefile example through R, but I'd try to provide more information of my sp dataframe:

`> class(bd)`

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY9li.png)"SpatialLinesDataFrame"
>
> attr(,"package")
>
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY9li.png) "sp"

[bd attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY9li.png)

> class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame
>
> features    : 8855
>
> extent      : 172.6811, 174.5966, -36.36374, -34.42634  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
>
> crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
>
> variables   : 134
>
> names       : OBJECTID_1,   Name_in_us,  Unique_ID, RAMM_Road_, iSequence,  SH, OBJECTID, ROADID,    RoadLength,      RoadNameAn, Displaceme, road_id, AvgWidth,     pave, CJNEX_urba, ...
>
> min values  :          1,     014-0000,    1188496,          0,         0,  No,        0,      0,             0, 012-0132  (805),    0-1008m,       0,        0, Concrete,      Rural, ...
>
> max values  :       5299, ZEALANDIA ST, 2044000001,       2065,       480, Yes,      999,   1683, 45826.7818765,     ZIDICH ROAD, 9925-9966m,    3520,     18.2, Unsealed,      Urban, ...

Polylines inside the df(bd@lines)

> $lines[[1000]]
>
> An object of class "Lines"
>
> Slot "Lines":
>
> [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY9li.png)]
>
> An object of class "Line"
>
> Slot "coords":
>
> ```
>      [,1]      [,2]
> ```
>
> [1,] 174.3629 -35.77290
>
> [2,] 174.3627 -35.77281
>
> [3,] 174.3624 -35.77276

`bd@data[1000,]`

> OBJECTID_1 Name_in_us Unique_ID RAMM_Road_ iSequence SH OBJECTID ROADID RoadLength       RoadNameAn Displaceme road_id AvgWidth ...
>
> 1000       1000  DOMAIN RD  1.16e+08        116         2 No       89    116   94.75686 DOMAIN RD  (116)      0-95m ...

The solution:
1. as answer/comment below 
2. use `bd[- grep("xcluded", bd$Notes),]` instead

Comment: HI Can you provide a minimal example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to create a shapefile in r.. like polylines with some attributes. I tried to provide more information of my sp df if this helps... otherwise, I think I need to upload part of my data

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe at this point that `bd` is a spatial object any more, or this:

```
bd@data[- grep("xcluded", bd@data$Notes),]
```

Is not the line producing this error:

```
Error: trying to get slot "data" from an object (class "data.frame") that is not an S4 object
```

The error says it is trying to get the data slot from a data frame. Its nothing todo with `grep` or subsetting.

I can replicate that error message:

```
> d = data.frame(x=1:10)
> d@data
Error: trying to get slot "data" from an object (class "data.frame") that is not an S4 object 
>
```

but I can't replicate that with a spatial sp-class object:

```
> Sldf
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 2 
extent      : 1, 3.05, 1, 3.05  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : NA 
variables   : 1
names       :  Z 
min values  : AA 
max values  : AB 
> Sldf@data
   Z
1 AA
2 AB
> Sldf@data[-grep("B",Sldf@data$Z),,drop=FALSE]
   Z
1 AA
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! Because I believe bd is a spatial object and I rerun my code to generate bd again, and your example reminds me I should use`bd[- grep("ROAD", bd$RoadNameAn),]` rather than `bd@data[- grep("ROAD", bd$RoadNameAn),]` otherwise I would lose my lines(in fact this is what I want to ask). In terms of the error, I think probably I rewrite `bd` by other stuff so it bring me the error.(Sorry for that)